# MSSQL Spatial index multiple predicate not using the index

Tags: indexing, azure-sql-database, spatial, sql-server-2016, sqlgeography

I have a Location table with a spatial index on the GeoLocation column. The following query works:

```
SELECT *
FROM Location WITH (INDEX (SpatialIndex_GeoLocation))
WHERE GeoLocation.STDistance(GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText('POINT(4.271942         
52.085289)', 4326)) < 50
```

However when adding a second predicate the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Location WITH (INDEX (SpatialIndex_GeoLocation))
WHERE GeoLocation.STDistance(GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText('POINT(4.271942         
52.085289)', 4326)) < 50
OR 
GeoLocation.STDistance(GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText('POINT(5.758871 52.7845827)', 4326)) < 50
```

The following exception is thrown:

The query processor could not produce a query plan for a query with a
spatial index hint.  Reason: Could not find required comparison predicate.
Try removing the index hints or removing SET FORCEPLAN.

Of course, removing the index hint will make the query work, but without using the index.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

A workaround in this case may be making use of the UNION operation as shown below:

```
SELECT *
FROM Location WITH (INDEX (SpatialIndex_GeoLocation))
WHERE GeoLocation.STDistance(GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText('POINT(4.271942         
52.085289)', 4326)) < 50
UNION 
SELECT *
FROM Location WITH (INDEX (SpatialIndex_GeoLocation))
WHERE
GeoLocation.STDistance(GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText('POINT(5.758871 52.7845827)', 4326)) < 50
```

Comment: The union does indeed work. The index is being used. However a union on the geography datatype is not allowed. This results in: The data type geography cannot be used as an operand to the UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operators because it is not comparable.

Also for my particular situation there are about 4000 or predicates, which would result in 4000 unions and a lot of work for me which isn't worth it at the moment. But thanks for your suggestion.